Variant of the Conway self-listing sequence
1 - 11 - 21 - 1211 - 111221 - 312211... you know this. Assume you don't code "runs", but instead list the "global" digit content. So 1 - 11 - 21 - 1112 - 3112 (the preceding number contains three ones and one three) etc. The process converges very fast to 21322314, and you can distill a self-ref sentence: 'This sentence contains 2 digits "1", 3 digits "2", 2 digits "3" and 1 digits "4".'
I think it is obvious you must run into a loop (I'm the Bob Beamon of jumping to conclusions). I won't ask for a list of all possible loops (I fear it's far too long - if I err here again, feel free to provide it) but only for the longest. My best so far is a loop period 3 with e.g. 51222314251617 - 41421314251617 - 51221334151617.
Conventions: Whereas 0 may occur e.g. if you previously have 10 "1", the nonexistence of a "6" of course will not be coded as "06" but simply omitted. My numbers are sorted ascending with multiplier first, but that is obviously irrelevant. We work in base 10 but the puzzle obviously works in any base.
Python cheat code:
import sys,random

def stp(st):
    so=""
    for ch in list(sorted(set(st))):
        so=so+str(st.count(ch))+ch
    return so

lm=0
for i in range(100000):
    ss=str(random.randrange(sys.maxsize))
    sf=stp(ss)
    ct=0
    while ss!=sf:
        ct+=1
        ss=stp(ss)
        sf=stp(stp(sf))
    sf=stp(ss)
    l=1
    while ss!=sf:
        l+=1
        sf=stp(sf)
    if l>lm:
        print(sf,l)
        lm=l

Tries to find a long permutation (rather ineffective) by random start and Pollard Rho.

What happens if there are ten or more of a given digit?

Certainly there are arbitrarily large fixed points of the form N13223141516...1(N-1)2N1(N+1)1(N+2)1(N+3) for any specific large N. So a classification of all loops indeed seems a bit hard to do. (But I'm not sure if I share your intuition that every sequence has to end in a loop. Why should that be obvious?)

@TimSeifert we only count single digits

@justhalf Ah okay, thank you. But why? That makes the question seem much more arbitrary I think

On that, most probably because this is not a new invention, but, as hinted in the first sentence of the question, that's the premise of the original formulation, which is related to run-length encoding.

@bobble: Just intuition, but as almost always, it's confirmed, see the lemma of AxiomaticSystem - there are only finitely many loops. (Good grief, 10^21 is still infinite for Python+my old PC, for all practical reasons :-)

We use a lemma:

 Every description with more than 21 digits describes a number longer than itself. Consequently, every number in a loop has at most 21 digits.
 Proof: For $n = 10a+b$ with $a>1$, any description with $n$ digits contains counts summing to at least $10^{a-2}(9b+10)$ (from a description with $b$ counts of $10^{a-1}$ and the other counts of $10^{a-2}$). For $n>21$, this number exceeds $n$.

This justifies the second line of this Python code, which checks all possible loops:

step = lambda tup:tuple((str(tup).count(str(j))*(j>0))+(tup[j]>0) for j in range(10)) #step of self-description
maxlen = 21 #longest possible looping number
dist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] #distribution of digits in current number
loops = dict()
flag = False
while True:
    dist[-1] += 1
    while sum(i*max(0,dist[i%10]-1) for i in range(1,11)) > maxlen: #any number describing only non-looping numbers isn't looping
        ind = -1
        while dist[ind] == 0: ind -= 1
        dist[ind] = 0
        try:dist[ind-1] += 1 #generate the next digit distribution
        except: flag = True
    if flag: break #if we reset the number of zeroes, we've checked all the numbers
    curr = tuple(dist)
    seen = []
    while True:
        if curr in loops: break
        if curr in seen:
            loops[curr] = len(seen)-seen.index(curr) #length of current loop
            if loops[curr] > 3: print(curr)
            break
        seen.append(curr)
        curr = step(curr)

print("Loops:",len(loops))
mx = max(loops.values())
print("Longest:",mx)
count = 0
for i in loops:
    if loops[i] == mx:
        count += 1
        print(i)
print("Count:",count)


which happily reports, after some time, that

 out of exactly 160 loops, the longest are length 3, and are precisely the ten loops obtained by replacing 6 and 7 in the original example with any two of {0,6,7,8,9}.


Is a number the "description" of the number up to digit order preceding it?  I must confess I cannot get my head around the lemma, the statement and why that statement, as well as the proof.  (It might be me, feel free to ignore...)

A description is any number of the form that the description process returns: i.e. a number of the form (count)(digit)(count)(digit)(count)(digit)...

But counts can be > 9, so a description is not immediately a number...

I'm surprised it's only 160. (And I'm sure that the possibility of counts >10 doesn't spoil the lemma, or at least can be patched easily.)
